# What character type is a slandered hero?

Tags: fiction, characters, archetypes

I am painting the hero of my major conflict with undeserved slander for most of the novel, then exposing the source of the slander. In effect, the reader experiences the villain becoming the hero.

I don’t believe this is an anti-hero.

### What is this character type?

**Example:**
Consider Spider-man, who is a superhero. He is constantly slandered by J. Jonah Jameson and the newspaper. Consider a story from the perspective of a devoted follower of that newspaper, who believes Spider-man is a villain.

Only at the end do you meet the superhero, and discover the smears. Spider-man is a villain and a menace for most of the story.

Comment: Is unreliable narration an issue for your story? Should your reader believe that your hero is actually a villain for the most of the story?

Comment: @Alexander Very much. They should trust the source implicitly. A strong case convicting then is built from several angles. The conspiracy is a shock. There is some first person unreliable narration, for sure: victims of the conspiracy.

Comment: So this sounds like [Good All Along](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GoodAllAlong) (TV Tropes warning), and [Sirius Black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sirius_Black) is one of the examples (typically an Anti-Hero).